# Dual boot 2 version of Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot

-I have windows 10 installed on a computer and want to make it in dual boot with windows 7 is it possible without removing 10 and then installing 7 and then reinstalling windows 10?

look at this two possibilities

1-
Windows 7 installed.
Install windows 10 dual boot (no problem it works)

but what i want is the following :

```
Windows 10 is installed
Install windows 7 in dual boot
```

Comment: I'd always recommend a VM to run an older OS on a newer machine. Safest that way.

Comment: If this is possible, is entirely dependent, on new your hardware is.

Comment: Sharing a common partition between two OS that differ by so much is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good Microsoft Article for doing that.

This is a fairly long and technical article. As I noted at the end, Virtual Machines are better, but if you wish to try this, make sure you read the entire article.

[Dual Boot Win 7 after Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-windows-7-after/7e43130f-11a9-4167-832e-97ed168ae369)

> 1. Your PC may refuse to boot and or unexpected PC crashes could
>    damage or even delete your files, so you should create an Image backup
>    your Windows 10 installation before you proceed to install Windows 7.
> 2. If you purchased a new computer with Windows 10 preinstalled then
>    check your manufacture’s support web site to see if there are Windows
>    7 (or 8.1) device drivers available. The lack of device drivers is a
>    good indication that your new computer is not Windows 7 compatible.
> 3. If you upgraded from Windows 7 or 8.1 to Windows 10 then you cannot
>    use your existing product key to re-install Windows 7 or 8.1 as it was
>    the basis for your free upgrade to Windows 10. Therefore you must
>    either have another unused product key and installation media or
>    purchase another copy (OEM or Retail) version of Windows 7 or 8.1,
>    note that anyone who offers to sell you just a product key without any
>    installation media may be a scammer.
> 4. Create an Image Backup of your existing Windows 10 installation
>    before you start the process of installing Windows 7 or 8.1
> 5. You will need to “Shrink” the existing Windows 10 partition to
>    create space (another partition) for Windows 7 or 8.1.
> 6. Once Windows 7 is installed you will need to re-install your
>    applications that are not compatible with Windows 10 so locate the
>    application(s) installation media and associated product key(s) that
>    need to be re-installed.

**However, better, I think** to avoid problems when reinstalling Windows 10 to do a Repair and subsequent boot issues, would be to make Windows 7 a Virtual Machine.

Virtual Machines will also allow you to more easily upgrade Windows 10 to Windows 11 when / if that time comes for you.

I use Virtual Machines and they work exceedingly well. Much recommended.